# Java finding minimum value from for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, minimum

I was having some problem when trying to find the minimum distance and from the minimum distance, I then plot two circles onto the map.

```
                    double distance = 0;
                    double minDistance;
                    convertedHotSpotGeomList = RetrieveHotSpotAsyncTask.convertedHotSpotGeom;
                    for(int i = 0; i < convertedHotSpotGeomList.size(); i++){
                        LatLng point1 = new LatLng(convertedHotSpotGeomList.get(i).getY(), convertedHotSpotGeomList.get(i).getX());                                 
                        LatLng point2 = new LatLng(convertedHotSpotGeomList.get(++i).getY(), convertedHotSpotGeomList.get(++i).getX());
                        distance = calculateHotSpot(point1, point2);
                        Log.i("DIST", String.valueOf(distance));
                        minDistance = distance;
                        if(minDistance < distance){
                            minDistance = distance;
                            Log.i("MIN", String.valueOf(minDistance));
                             CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
                                .center(point1)
                                .radius(1000)
                                .fillColor(Color.argb(95, 178, 30, 37))
                                .strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                                googleBasemap.addCircle(circleOptions);

                                CircleOptions circleOptions1= new CircleOptions()
                                .center(point2)
                                .radius(1000)
                                .fillColor(Color.argb(95, 88, 130, 37))
                                .strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                                googleBasemap.addCircle(circleOptions1);

                        }
                    }
```

Currently I am getting 15, 3, 15, 14 as DIST but I could not get the minDist as it is not printed out. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand, you are looking for the minimum distance between any points on each circle? Maybe a math formula will give it.

Comment: Nope, because I have to calculate the distance between two points. Then for the minimum distance for two point, I get plot two circle on it and find the mid point of these two points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want:

```
    distance = calculateHotSpot(point1, point2);
    ....
    if(distance < minDistance){  
        minDistance = distance;
```

and initialize `minDistance` to `Double.MAX_VALUE`: `double minDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE`

The original few lines does not make much sense, because `minDistance < distance` would never evaluates to true since you just set `minDistance = distance;`

```
    distance = calculateHotSpot(point1, point2);
    ....
    minDistance = distance;
    if(minDistance < distance){ // will never happen
        minDistance = distance;
```

**Updated:**

More complete solution as the point above is not the only issue:

```
double minDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
convertedHotSpotGeomList = RetrieveHotSpotAsyncTask.convertedHotSpotGeom;
LatLng[] minPoints = new LatLng[2]; // save the minimum points
for(int i = 0; i < convertedHotSpotGeomList.size(); i++){
    LatLng point1 = new LatLng(convertedHotSpotGeomList.get(i).getY(),   convertedHotSpotGeomList.get(i).getX());                                 
    LatLng point2 = new LatLng(convertedHotSpotGeomList.get(++i).getY(), convertedHotSpotGeomList.get(++i).getX());
    distance = calculateHotSpot(point1, point2);
    Log.i("DIST", String.valueOf(distance));
    if(distance < minDistance){
        minDistance = distance;
        Log.i("MIN", String.valueOf(minDistance));
        minPoints[0] = point1;
        minPoints[1] = point2;
    }
}
// we finish all the comparison, so we draw the circles now 
if(minPoints[0]!=null && minPoints[1] !=null){
    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
        .center(minPoints[0])
        .radius(1000)
        .fillColor(Color.argb(95, 178, 30, 37))
        .strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    CircleOptions circleOptions1= new CircleOptions()
        .center(minPoints[1])
        .radius(1000)
        .fillColor(Color.argb(95, 88, 130, 37))
        .strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    googleBasemap.addCircle(circleOptions);
    googleBasemap.addCircle(circleOptions1);
}
```

Comment: So I declare my minDistance as 0 or?

Comment: @IWasSoLost Use `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, let me update in my answer

Comment: I see but how do I make sure that it's only the minDistance then I plot the circle? Because currently I am getting two sets of circles on the map. With the minDistance printed out as 15 and 3

Comment: @IWasSoLost Ok, I you have another issues in the code, let me include it in my post as well.

Comment: @IWasSoLost OK, please check it out the updated post

Comment: I see. So basically you do a comparison for each point to get the minimum and store it to minPoint[] before plotting it onto the map. Am I correct?

Comment: @IWasSoLost Yes, that's the general idea, but we only count the distance of adjacent points (I didn't change your main algorithm), I'm not so sure it is fine for the problem you are solving (i.e. among [A, B, C, D], we only find the minimum value between A and B, B and C, C and D). Anyway, you should be able to handle the rest, cheers!

Comment: Let's say if I wanted to count it in a way like not according to adjacent points, what algorithm should I use?

Comment: Also, I am trying to get the mid point between these two points. Help me take a look at this thread when you free: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282578/calculating-midpoint-from-two-coordinates

Comment: @IWasSoLost If they are simply numbers, we can sort them first in O(nlogn), and then apply the current code since they are already sorted. But it would be a little bit tricky to sort them now since they are not just a number.

Comment: I see but can you help me take a look at the thread I posted to you? I am trying to get the midPoint between these two points and draw a circle

Comment: Hello, can you help me take a look at this thread? The problem is not solved yet and I have no idea why. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282578/calculating-midpoint-from-two-coordinates/28282730?noredirect=1#comment44921431_28282730

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies in these two lines next to each other:

```
                    minDistance = distance;
                    if(minDistance < distance){
```

So first you are setting minDistance to the value of distance. Then you are checking to see if minDistance is less than distance. Since it will **never** be less than the value you just set it to, that block of code will never evaluate.