# Calculating midpoint from two coordinates

Tags: java, algorithm, google-maps, math, coordinate

I was having some problem when trying to find the mid point between two point. Here is the part where I get the shortest distance between two point:

```
                    double distance = 0;
                    double minDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;

                    convertedHotSpotGeomList = RetrieveHotSpotAsyncTask.convertedHotSpotGeom;
                    LatLng[] minPoints = new LatLng[2]; 

                    for(int i = 0; i < convertedHotSpotGeomList.size(); i++){
                        LatLng point1 = new LatLng(convertedHotSpotGeomList.get(i).getY(),   convertedHotSpotGeomList.get(i).getX());                                 
                        LatLng point2 = new LatLng(convertedHotSpotGeomList.get(++i).getY(), convertedHotSpotGeomList.get(++i).getX());

                        distance = calculateDistance(point1, point2);
                        if(distance < minDistance){
                            minDistance = distance;
                            minPoints[0] = point1;
                            minPoints[1] = point2;
                        }
                    }

                    // Finish all the comparison and draw the circles
                    if(minPoints[0]!=null && minPoints[1] !=null){
                        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
                            .center(minPoints[0])
                            .radius(1000)
                            .fillColor(Color.argb(95, 178, 30, 37))
                            .strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        CircleOptions circleOptions1= new CircleOptions()
                            .center(minPoints[1])
                            .radius(1000)
                            .fillColor(Color.argb(95, 88, 130, 37))
                            .strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                        googleBasemap.addCircle(circleOptions);
                        googleBasemap.addCircle(circleOptions1);

                        midPoint(minPoints[0].latitude,minPoints[0].longitude,minPoints[1].latitude,minPoints[1].longitude);
                    }
                }
```

And then from the center point of the two circles I drawn, I am calling this method to get the midpoint:

```
private void midPoint(double lat1,double lon1,double lat2,double lon2){
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);

    lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
    lon1 = Math.toRadians(lon1);

    double Bx = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);
    double By = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dLon);
    double lat3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(lat1) + Math.sin(lat2), Math.sqrt((Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) * (Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) + By * By));
    double lon3 = lon1 + Math.atan2(By, Math.cos(lat1) + Bx);

    Log.i("LAT", String.valueOf(lat3));
    Log.i("LON", String.valueOf(lon3));
    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
    .center(new LatLng(lon3, lat3))
    .radius(1000)
    .fillColor(Color.argb(95, 178, 30, 137))
    .strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    googleBasemap.addCircle(circleOptions);
}
```

At the midpoint, I wanted to draw another circle onto the google map. However, when I print out the lat and lng for the mid point, I am getting this:

```
LAT 0.02512664 LON 1.811859
```

From what I've known, the coordinate of google map should be in 103. , 1. . I guess it's because the format is different and that's why the third circle is not coming out. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all shortest distance between two points sounds little strange. As far as I know there is only one distance between points. The median of two coordinates is simply M((lat1+lat2)/2, (lng1+lng2)/2)

Comment: Opps sorry for the poor explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 double lat3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(lat1) +...
 double lon3 = lon1 + Math.atan2(By, Math.cos(lat1) + Bx);
```

This returns radians. Go to degrees:

```
double latdeg = Math.toDegrees(lat3);
double londeg = Math.toDegrees(lon3);


103.81187377279383
1.4396504253445948
```

Comment: But if I changed it, I am redrawing the first two circle which is the minPoints[] instead of drawing a third circle in between the two points. Any ideas?

Comment: What should midPoint compute, i.e., from where is the formula you have coded there?

Comment: I've been calling midPoint(0,0,i,i) for i = 0(1)90 and the results (after adding Math.toDegrees) look quite reasonable. With which values are you calling midPoint where you don't get the expected result?

Comment: I am passing in the minPoints[0] and minPoints[1] which are the nearest between each other. By right both of them are at the top center of the map, but then when I call the midPoint that method, it supposed to draw out one circle between them. Instead, the two circles previously were redrawn at the bottom center of the map. Any ideas?

Comment: @IWasSoLost Are you saying that `midPoint()` doesn't redraw a new circle, but it just redraw two cricles again for `midPoints[0]` and `midPoints[1]` ?

Comment: @PauLo Yeah sorry for my poor English

Comment: I mean the actual numerical values of the midPoint call (that, according to you, returns the coordinates of one of these two points).

Comment: You can't redraw *two* circles with one command, i.e., the one at the end of method midPoint.

Comment: Yeah it did returned me a midPoint but I not sure how come the two circles shifted. It only happens after I execute the midPoint()

Comment: The numeric values? If they are correct the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: The numeric values are correct. Sorry about that, it's something wrong with the drawing part